# Facing Issue while configuring Fedex shipping method

Tags: shipping-methods, soap, fedex

Tried to configure fedex with magento 2 and refered the following url:
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/

Shipping method for fedex is visible on front end but not being enable even after disabling the soap cache.

Log exception is : 
main.CRITICAL: SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in
\Magento_13\vendor\magento\module-fedex\Model\Carrier.php:491 
Stack trace:

## 0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('https://wsbeta....', 'getRates', 1, 0)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i am finding something related to FedEx itself as I am facing the same issue in Magento 1.9 for my client and came up with a post with the same question as you have.

**It was suggested there to try on the different network.It may be of blocked I.P issue**

Hope it will help you.Sorry, i am not getting that question link but only this is suggested there .

Hope it help you at least.

Comment: @ Saurabh Ranjan : Is it solved now ?